# (FIXED) Substrate forkless upgrade tutorial: pallet_scheduler has breaking changes

Tags: rust, runtime-upgrade, error, config

(*This question was originally asked here:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056703/substrate-forkless-upgrade-tutorial-pallet-scheduler-has-breaking-changes)

I am following the Substrate [forkless upgrade tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades/) and have added

```
pallet-scheduler = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
```

to my Cargo.toml. However, when I try to build the runtime with the command

```
cargo build --release -p node-template-runtime
```

the process fails and I get the following error message:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: PreimageProvider, NoPreimagePostponement
```

It seems that this appears to be a newer version and requires me to specify `NoPreimagePostponement` and `PreimageProvider` types in `pallet_scheduler::Config`.

How can I set those parameters? https://docs.rs/pallet-scheduler/latest/pallet_scheduler/trait.Config.html doesn't seem to have those properties.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been fixed upstream.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is a new version for the Scheduler pallet and the tutorial needs to be updated according to it.  [This pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10356) mentions the necessary changes. In the meantime, just set the following to imitate the desired behavior:

```
type PreimageProvider = ();
type NoPreimagePostponement = ();
```

Comment: Glad this worked! When you see an issue in the docs, please do be so kind as to open an issue - or if you have a solution, a PR :) - so we can get that fixed up! Perhaps this was you? https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/1003

Comment: That was not me, I just encountered the same error yesterday when trying to complete the tutorial. But indeed, those commits fixed the tutorial :)